# Determine if $f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2 + \min(x+2y+z, (x+2y+z)^2)$ is convex.

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-analysis

> Consider the following function:
>   $$f(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2 + \min(x+2y+z, (x+2y+z)^2)$$
>   Determine if this function is convex or not.

So I know for a convex function, any two points $x_1$, and $x_2$

$f(cx_1+(1-c)x_2)\leq cf(x_1) + (1-c)f(x_2)$
where $0 \leq c \leq1$ 
is true

I get the feeling the question wants me to find a counter example to this principle, but I have been staring at it for hours and cannot find 2 points, and I'm not really sure how to prove its %100 true.

Comment: Please verify the edit.

Comment: Break your min up into a piecewise of sorts. My hunch (and it may be incorrect) is that min works out to $x+2y+z$ whenever $x+2y+z>1$ or $<0,$ and $(x+2y+z)^2$ otherwise.

Comment: try $x=y=z=1$ and $x=y=z=0.$

Comment: this results in 2.75 < 3.5

Comment: Intuitively I think it is convex. In the 1d case you would have, say,$ f(x)=x^2 + min(2x, (2x)^2) = x^2 + 2x$ for $x<0,$ $x>1$ and $f(x)=5x^2$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1.$ That one is convex for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function is NOT convex:

There exist cases where

$$\frac{1}{2}(f(a, b, c) + f(a', b', c')) < f\left(\frac{a+a'}{2},\frac{b+b'}{2},\frac{c+c'}{2}\right)$$

It suffices to take $a=0.6, b=0.55, c=-1, a'=0.7,b'=0.75, c'=-1$ and we have

$$\frac{1}{2}(f(0.6, 0.55, -1) + f(0.7, 0.75, -1)) - f(0.65, 0.65, -1)=-0.045$$

**Edit 1:** How did I find these values ? By blocking the value of $z$ (here it is "blocked" at $z_0=-1$) and representing the surface $z=f(x,y,z_0)$. My attention was attracted by the little gutter I saw on the first picture below, and I selected two points on both sides of the limits of this gutter.

**Edit 2 :** There is a much simpler method to display evidence of non-convexity. It suffices to consider:

$$f(x,0,0)=min(x^2+x,x^2)$$

See Figure 2. No supplementary comment is necessary...

[image]

(Figure 1)

[image]

(Figure 2)

Comment: Is there an intuitive way of recognizing these boundary conditions without using plotting software?

Comment: @Martin: In such a case, where the function is so close to be convex, it's hard not to study it numerically through plots, etc. But, since I have given my answer, I have a simpler answer that I will add under the form of an Edit, and that one can consider as a kind of method.

Comment: New edit done...